# In LibreOffice Calc, How To Access Raw HTML in a Cell?

Tags: html, libreoffice, openoffice.org, libreoffice-calc, openoffice-calc

I have a LibreOffice Calc spreadsheet that has a column with HTML formatting in it, including links. There is some data in the HTML that I need to preserve and extract. This would be easy to do if I could access the raw HTML, but I cannot figure out how to access the raw HTML within LibreOffice itself, nor can I figure out how to export it.

I would ideally like to find a solution of some sort of formula or function I could place in a new column, which would make that column display the raw HTML so that I can work with it using basic string operations. Alternatively if there is some sort of in-app command like a change of formatting in the menu or a way to use "Paste Special..." to view the HTML, I could do that too.

Failing this, I could settle for a solution that would preserve the raw HTML when exporting the data to CSV format or some other easily-parsable format. I have unfortunately not figured out how to do this either; when I export to CSV the HTML formatting is lost.

As a last resort I would be open to a custom macro using basic but I would rather find a simpler solution.

I have also tagged this as OpenOffice because I suspect this question may only be relevant to aspects of LibreOffice that have not changed from OpenOffice, although if this is not the case I would be interested to know about it!

Comment: If your CSV export "removes" the HTML formatting, it is not contained in the cell. Would you mind to [edit] your question and add a [mre], please? For example, you could make a screenshot snippet which shows the formatting, and the edit field atop of the spread sheet, or any other view you see fit.

Comment: I don't see what such a screenshot would show, the edit field does not show any HTML, it just shows text. If I export a file in `.fods` format, however, it saves the HTML in a modified format, for example, the contents of a single cell might read `<text:p><text:a xlink:href="https://www.mass.gov/doc/black-cohosh/download" xlink:type="simple">Black Cohosh</text:a></text:p>`. The edit field shows only the text "Black Cohosh" with no formatting and it shows it as a single, un-editable block. Clearly it is storing the `<p>` element and the link, but I don't know how to access it within the sheet.

Comment: Would you mind to [edit] your question and add a simple step-by-step example how apply HTML formatting to a cell, please? This looks to me as a rarely used feature that only few people know. -- Or do you mean you have a _hyperlink_ in a cell? (Unfortunately it is late in the night here, need to get some sleep.)

Comment: I did not apply HTML formatting to the cell, the spreadsheet arrived to me this way. The only way I know how to create such HTML formatting in a cell is when copying-and-pasting highlighted material from a web browser, into the spreadsheet, using "Paste Special" and selecting "HTML". It then preserves (some of) the HTML in the cells. I suspect that is how the HTML in the sheet I am working with originated, but I am not sure.

Comment: ***when I export to CSV the HTML formatting is lost*** (Just a guess) If you select and copy the entire column, and then paste it into Notepad, for example, is the HTML text distorted a lot? *If I came across such a file, I would not waste time on decryption, but would request a file in a different format (or a link to a page on the Internet)*

Comment: After experimenting several hours with Calc and LibreOffice BASIC (and especially its bad documentation) I gave up. It seems as if you cannot access the "raw" contents of a cell that includes hyperlinks. -- However, perhaps some Python expert will try. The Python API might be broader than the BASIC API. Or use some UNO service? -- Until then storing the file as "fods" (uncompressed "ods", which actually is just a ZIP archive) and trying to parse that is your best bet. Good luck!

Comment: @JohnSUN Copy'n'paste of such cells into an editor obtains only the visible text.

Comment: If this is something you don't mind doing manually and not a ton of work, I would suggest opening the ODS using a "unzip" program (like 7-zip in Windows), then access the "content.xml". Upload the content to a "XML beautifier" then find your cell info contained within `<table:table-cell ...>`.

Comment: I am starting to think best option is export to `.fods` format, then write custom code to parse the data there. I was hoping that there would be a native or built-in solution, but any of these steps would be at least as time-consuming. It really surprises me that this isn't easily supported or documented. Perhaps this problem is less suited to a Stack Overflow question and more suited to making a feature request directly to LibreOffice. It seems a bit odd to allow storage of HTML data but not allow easy access to the raw HTML. I'd expect a built-in spreadsheet function to do this.